# Wrapping a template function call in a macro, or avoid specializing a void return

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I have the following function that allows me to wrap OpenGL commands and log when something goes wrong:

```
template<typename Res, typename Func, typename... Args>
struct Checker {
    static Res run(const std::string& function_name, Func&& func, Args&&... args) {
        Res result = func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        check_and_log_error(function_name);
        return result;
    }
};

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
struct Checker<void, Func, Args...> {
    static void run(const std::string& function_name, Func&& func, Args&&... args) {
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        check_and_log_error(function_name);
    }
};

template<typename Func>
struct Checker<void, Func> {
    static void run(const std::string& function_name, Func&& func) {
        func();
        check_and_log_error(function_name);
    }
};

}

template<typename Res=void, typename Func, typename... Args>
Res _GLCheck(const std::string& function_name, Func&& func, Args&&... args) {
    GLThreadCheck::check();
    return GLChecker::Checker<Res, Func, Args...>::run(function_name, std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I'd like to wrap _GLCheck in a macro, so that the function name parameter is supplied automatically, e.g.

```
#define GLCheck(...) _GLCheck(__func__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

This works fine provided that the GL call doesn't return a value, but if it does then _GLCheck must be instantiated like this:

```
program_object_ = _GLCheck<GLuint>(__func__, glCreateProgram);
```

Obviously my macro fails when I need to specify the return type like that. Is there some way to either:

- Write a better macro to deal with this situation, or...
- Avoid having to explicitly define the return type by altering the template functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to recognize that the template argument to `_GLCheck` is intended to be the same type as is returned by `Func`.  Therefore:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
auto _GLCheck(const std::string& function_name, Func&& func, Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(func(args...)) {
// ...
```

First I tried with `decltype` on the front, but I think that's not workable, so you get the above ugliness.  :)

Comment: Why ugliness? That's what the trailing return type was inveted for.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a macro. Instead do something like:

```
ObjectThatWillLogInItsDestructor obj(function_name);
return function_returning_void();
```